# ExtJS arrowHandler needs to reference the splitbutton it is part of

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the following code, the Ext.getCmp's do not work, because they aren't completely defined when they're being called. How can I grab those two things?

Also, there is another part of code continually pushing to list.menu.buttons, so that's why I need them added to items only when the arrow is clicked.

```
xtype: "splitbutton",
id: "list",
enableToggle: true,
arrowHandler: (function () {
                var library = Ext.getCmp("library");
                var buttons = Ext.getCmp("list").menu.buttons;
            function btn(num) {
                var image = new Image;
                image.src = buttons[num].dataURL;
                this.xtype = "button";
                this.height = 50;
                this.width = 50;
                this.icon = image;
                this.num = num;
                this.handler = function (btn) {
                    btn.up("button").fireEvent("selected", this.num);
                };
            }
            for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
                library.push(new btn(i));
        })(),
menu: {
    plain: true,
    buttons: [],                            
    items: [
        {
            xtype: "ribbon_gallery",
            columns: 3,
            title: "Recent",
            id: "recent",
            items: []
        },
        {
            xtype: "ribbon_gallery",
            columns: 3,
            title: "Library",
            id: "library",
            itemId: "library",
            items: []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have specified a [self-invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) function to the *arrowHandler* config

```
  arrowHandler: (function() {...})()
```

You need a "normal" function

```
  arrowHandler: function() {...}
```